# Creating blank node when value in not present

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to read and format a XML data. I am reading the data using XSLT. I am facing some issue in that. Could someone help me on this.

I have an XML input where I have only 1 parent node and the rest of XML hierarchy is a flat hierarchy.

```
<employee>
    <Name>ABC</Name>
    <Department>IT</Department>
    <Age>30</Age>
    <Salary>40000</Salary>

    <Name>XYZ</Name>
    <Department>IT</Department>
    <Age>25</Age>
    <Salary>30000</Salary>
</employee>
```

Here Name node is mandatory node and rest are optional nodes. My requirement is if any optional node is not present in the input XML then I'll create a blank node for it.

but code is failing in the below scenario where I do not have  node for first employee.

```
<employee>
    <Name>ABC</Name>
    <Department>IT</Department>
    <Age>30</Age>

    <Name>XYZ</Name>
    <Department>IT</Department>
    <Age>25</Age>
    <Salary>30000</Salary>
</employee>
```

The code I have written is

```
<xsl:element name="Employee_Information">
    <xsl:for-each select="Name">
        <xsl:variable name="positionVariable">
            <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:element name="Employee_Name">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="Employee_Dept">
            <xsl:value-of select="../Department[number($positionVariable)]"/>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="Employee_Name">
            <xsl:value-of select="../Age[number($positionVariable)]"/>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="Employee_Name">
            <xsl:value-of select="../Salary[number($positionVariable)]"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:element>
```

This is working fine when all the data are coming in the input but in the mentioned scenario its giving output like below

```
<employee>
    <Name>ABC</Name>
    <Department>IT</Department>
    <Age>30</Age>
    <Salary>30000</Salary>
    <Name>XYZ</Name>
    <Department>IT</Department>
    <Age>25</Age>
    <Salary></Salary>
</employee>
```

Its creating blank node for wrong employee. Its creating blank node for the second employee where blank node should be created for the first employee.

Please let me know if you want any other information.
thank you very much in advance.
Kaushik

Comment: Are you using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0?

Comment: I am using XSLT 1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, this is a *grouping* problem. In XSLT 2.0, it would be trivial to solve using:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="Name">
```

Doing the equivalent in XSLT 1.0 is a bit more tricky:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="grp" match="Department|Age|Salary" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::Name[1])" />

<xsl:template match="/employee">
    <Employee_Information>
        <xsl:for-each select="Name">
            <xsl:variable name="current-group" select="key('grp', generate-id())" />
            <Employee_Name>
                <xsl:value-of select="." />
            </Employee_Name>
            <Employee_Dept>
                <xsl:value-of select="$current-group[self::Department]" />
            </Employee_Dept>
            <Employee_Age>
                <xsl:value-of select="$current-group[self::Age]" />
            </Employee_Age>
            <Employee_Salary>
                <xsl:value-of select="$current-group[self::Salary]" />
            </Employee_Salary>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Employee_Information>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Wow!! its working.. thanks very much Michael for the solution.